# Getting error in migration, "Syntax error or access violation:1064"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to insert a json string in to my Laravel 5.2 migration and I get an error, "Syntax error or access violation:1064".

I currently using MySQL version 5.6.17 as my database.

This is from my migration file:

```
 Schema::create('profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->json('settings')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Can i somehow make this happen with my MySQL database or do i need to switch it up with MongoDB?

Comment: Does it work without nullable() chained on the end?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: @btl No unfortunately not.

Comment: @patricus I got 5.6.17 as my version.

Comment: And what happens if you remove $table->json('settings')->nullable(); entirely and run the migration?

Comment: @btl Then it will work correctly.

Comment: @DavidOlsson, please choose one of the answers as best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.2, the `$table->json()` method will try to create an actual JSON field in the database. However, the JSON field was not added to MySQL until MySQL 5.7.8.

Therefore, if you're using a version of MySQL previous to 5.7.8, you need to just create it as a `text` field (which is how Laravel < 5.2 handles it).

Comment: I'm using a text instead and it work fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use MySQL 5.7.8 or higher to use `json` columns.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/table-json-generates-an-error-when-running-migrations

You could update your MySQL version, or you could try to use `text` as alternative. If it will not work as is, you could decode and encode your json data before and after using DB.